# mysql, check exists first, or just attempt to update?

Tags: mysql

Currently, when a user clicks a notification on my site, I check it exists first before setting it as read. Is that wasteful? Would there be any issues if I simply did an update query?

Right now:

```
$check_note = $dbl->run("SELECT 1 FROM `user_notifications` WHERE `id` = ? AND `owner_id` = ?", array((int) $_GET['clear_note'], (int) $_SESSION['user_id']))->fetchOne();
if ($check_note)
{
    // they have seen it and when they saw it
    $dbl->run("UPDATE `user_notifications` SET `seen` = 1, `seen_date` = ? WHERE `id` = ?", array(core::$date, (int) $_GET['clear_note']));
}
```

Would it just be better to do this?

```
$dbl->run("UPDATE `user_notifications` SET `seen` = 1, `seen_date` = ? WHERE `id` = ? AND `owner_id` = ?", array(core::$date, (int) $_GET['clear_note'], (int) $_SESSION['user_id']));
```

Comment: You just update, assuming that you did create a correct unique index in the database. The MySQL adapter offers error handling, so you can check after the UPDATE if it was successful.

Comment: Normally there's no need to hard-cast with `(int)` if you're using prepared statements.

Comment: Why not use [`INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)? You'll need a `UNIQUE` constraint for this to work properly.

Comment: In general, try to reduce the number of queries. The database has to do just as much work to process your `SELECT` query as to test if there are any rows to update.

Comment: @tadman He's not doing an `INSERT` when the `SELECT` doesn't find anything.

Comment: Thanks, I've done some testing and it's fine with the update statement by itself. Seems there was no need to check if it exists first, since mysql doesnt need to do anything if it doesn't.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, misread. You're right there. An `UPDATE` that's expected to intermittently fail is probably best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the update. If there's nothing that matches the `WHERE` condition, it won't do anything. The database has to do just as much work to test the condition during the `UPDATE` as it does in the `SELECT`, so you're not saving it any work, you're just doing an extra, redundant query.